# java.lang.IllegalStateException: HTC Android 6.0 Marshmallow crash - Google Play Snapshots

Tags: java, android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-play-games

I have an app released that works great on most phones ranging from Android 4.X to 7.X. But there is one device, an HTC One M9 (6.0 Marshmallow) and the app crashes everytime. It always happens when the main menu is loaded and the app tries to connect to google play games services. To be honest, I don't get the error log. This is what i get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must provide a valid file name!
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1616)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1561)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.IGamesService$Stub$Proxy.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.GamesClientImpl.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$2.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl$2.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaad$zza.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaq.zze(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaq.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaav.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaat.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.SnapshotsImpl.open(Unknown Source)
    at com.duke.privatpc.quiztest.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:362)
    at com.duke.privatpc.quiztest.MainActivity$2.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:357)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 4 more
```

Also, the two lines in the log referring to my MainActivity.java within these methods (here at "Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult open"):

```
private void savedGamesUpdate() {
        final String snapshotName = makeSnapshotName(APP_STATE_KEY);
        final boolean createIfMissing = true;

        // Use the data from the EditText as the new Snapshot data.
        final byte[] data = mSaveGameData;

        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> updateTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {


            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult open = Games.Snapshots.open(
                        mGoogleApiClient, snapshotName, createIfMissing).await();

                if (!open.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return false;
                }

                Bitmap coverImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.autosave);
                String desc = "Autosave "+android.os.Build.MODEL;
                // Create the change operation
                SnapshotMetadataChange metadataChange = new SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder()
                        .setCoverImage(coverImage)
                        .setDescription(desc)
                        .build();

                // Change data but leave existing metadata
                Snapshot snapshot = open.getSnapshot();
                snapshot.getSnapshotContents().writeBytes(data);

                Snapshots.CommitSnapshotResult commit = Games.Snapshots.commitAndClose(
                        mGoogleApiClient, snapshot, metadataChange).await();

                if (!commit.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    return false;
                }

                // No failures
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                dismissProgressDialog();

            }
        };
        updateTask.execute();
    }
```

and this one:

```
   private String makeSnapshotName(int appStateKey) {
        if(isAnHTCDevice()){
            return "Autosave HTC";
        }else{
            if(android.os.Build.MODEL != null){
                return "Autosave"+android.os.Build.MODEL;
            }else{
                return "Autosave";
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean isAnHTCDevice()
    {
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if (manufacturer.toLowerCase().contains("htc"))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Anyone know what the cause for this could be?

Answer (score 0):

RTFM. as refered in the document, [Snapshots.open](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots.html#open(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient, java.lang.String, boolean))

> The name of the snapshot file to open. Must be between 1 and 100 non-URL-reserved characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or the symbols "-", ".", "_", or "~").

so, modify makeSnapshotName method to generate a valid filename.

Comment: Can you explain a bit where i did something wrong then? I don't see where i create an Snapshot name that does not meet these requirements? Or does it not accept the space in "Autosave HTC"?

Comment: @DustinKeßler `Autosave HTC`, white space is not allowed.

Comment: How come that i do savegames at other places that are called "Manual Savepoint" and it works fine?